# Woocmerce checkout page webview

Tags: woocommerce, webview, checkout, endpoint

I have woocommerce project integrate with mobile app and I want to open checkout page on mobile for the logged in user
How to get the woocommerce checkout as webview in the mobile app?
if there is away to return checkout page for specific user as webview?

Comment: Solved , you can use the access token and make authentication by wc_set_customer_auth_cookie( ) method. but I have another problem that the payment methods not loaded in the webview

Answer (score 0):

Solved , you can use the access token and make authentication by wc_set_customer_auth_cookie( ) method. but I have another problem that the payment methods not loaded in the webview

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).